# C++ compiler error: 'not declared in this scope'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

My program checks how many students pass/fail an exam.

I thought I had already declared `i` previously but the compiler still shows the following error:

```
 "[Error] 'i' was not declared in this scope"
```

Additionally, the line containing: `l.checkPass(i)` in the `grade_test.cpp` is marked red, if I change it to: `l.checkPass(int i)`, the compiler says:

```
 [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'
```

Here is my code:

`grade.h`:

```
class Grade
{
    int mid_term, final;
    int total;  

    public:
        int i;
        Grade *next;
        Grade();
        Grade(int i_mid_term, int i_final, int i_total);
        void readFile(string _file);
        void printList();
        void subString(string s);
        int Show();
        void addTail(Grade *q);
        int checkPass(int i);
};

#endif
```

`grade.cpp`:

```
int Grade::Show()
    {
        cout << mid_term << "-" << final << "-" << total << endl;
        if (mid_term < 4 || final < 4 || total < 10)
        {
            cout << "fail" << endl;
            i = i;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "pass" << endl;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

int Grade::checkPass(int i)
    {
        cout << i << " student passed." << endl;
        cout << 6-i << " student failed." << endl; 
    }
```

`grade_test.cpp`:

```
int main()
{
    Grade l;
    l.readFile("mark.txt");
    l.printList(); 
    l.checkPass(i); 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

### Question:

What could be the cause of the errors?

Comment: What do you think the expression `i = i` would accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `i` as the argument of `Grade::checkPass()`.

Try changing the files like this:

grade.h

```
class Grade
{
    int mid_term, final;
    int total;  

    public:
        int i;
        Grade *next;
        Grade();
        Grade(int i_mid_term, int i_final, int i_total);
        void readFile(string _file);
        void printList();
        void subString(string s);
        int Show();
        void addTail(Grade *q);
        int checkPass(); // remove "int i"
};

#endif
```

grade.cpp

```
int Grade::Show()
    {
        cout << mid_term << "-" << final << "-" << total << endl;
        if (mid_term < 4 || final < 4 || total < 10)
        {
            cout << "fail" << endl;
            // i = i; // not harmful but do nothing
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "pass" << endl;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

int Grade::checkPass() // remove "int i" so that it will see the member variable i
    {
        cout << i << " student passed." << endl;
        cout << 6-i << " student failed." << endl; 
    }
```

grade_test.cpp

```
int main()
{
    Grade l;
    l.readFile("mark.txt");
    l.printList(); 
    l.checkPass();  // remove "i"
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to pass the value of 'i' from the Show() function to the checkPass() function, so that's why I put in the parameter. I tried removing 'int i' as you said, the program run but the result is not as I expected.

Comment: I think this will eliminate the compile error, but the behavior of this code may not be good. For example, why `i` is updated by just calling `Grade::Show()`? This is comfusing and may create some troubles.

Comment: Maybe `Grade::readFile(string _file)`, `Grade::Grade()` or `Grade::printList()`, which are not shown here, are not working well.

Comment: readfile, Grade, printList are all in my code, I post the error parts only.

Comment: @Marco: `i` is a member variable. It's always there, inside `Grade`. You do not need to and should not pass it from anywhere to anywhere! In this case you tried to pass a _different_ `i`, one that didn't exist, from `main`. You got it right in `Show()` but got it wrong in `checkPass()`.

Comment: so how do I use the value of 'i' from Show() function in checkPass() function? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

In your main, you don't have any variable i declared that's why your compiler give you that error.

```
int Grade::checkPass(int i)
{
    cout << i << " student passed." << endl;
    cout << 6-i << " student failed." << endl; 
}
```

The int i will enter in conflict with the public variable i you declared in you class.